# Replicate only certain databases

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

I have one instance of database on local server, another on remote. So when internet is gone, application works on local database. After internet connection is reestablished I want to sync these two databases. I have two questions:

1. How to replicate only one database. (there are several databases on instance);
2. I have only succeeded to replicate instances on same machine (when one host is localhost and another is remote instance, it throws error), how to replicate database on different machines?

Answer (score 0):

- How to replicate only one database. (there are several databases on instance);

You can make the other database as [Arbiter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/). It does not have a copy of data.

- I have only succeeded to replicate instances on same machine (when one host is localhost and another is remote instance, it throws error), how to replicate database on different machines?

looks like a network setup problem to me. [Test Connections Between all Members](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-replica-sets/)